# how to put a button and search input inline in a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to make a search bar. How can I make the "go" button and the search input be inline? I have put my code below, but I am not sure where the error is.

```html
<div style="float:right;display:inline;">
  
  <div>
  
    <button class="ui-btn  ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-mini" style="margin:0 0 0 
             0;padding: 0 0 0 0;">GO!
    </button>
   
    <input name="searchword" id="search" value="" placeholder="Placeholder text..." 
           type="search" />
   
  </div>  


</div>
```

Comment: Besides the slight height difference, what is wrong with your current code?

Comment: Marc Audet,me too i don't understand ,the search button moves to the next line,I want all of them to be on the same line

Comment: i thought removing the padding and margin on the button could fix things ,the reason for the slight height difference

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine.

If you want it to be exact, remove the sub-wrapping div, make the button 20px and use display: inline-flex; instead of inline. Maybe it will be what want

Comment: Dont expect browsers to render exactly. They all render differently so always set at least your button height.

Answer (score 0):

jQM wraps the input in a div. you can assign a css class to the wrapper using the **[data-wrapper-class](http://api.jquerymobile.com/textinput/#option-wrapperClass)** attribute:

```
<div style="float:right;display:inline;">
    <div>
        <button class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-mini btnclass">GO!</button>
        <input name="searchword" id="search" value="" placeholder="Placeholder text..." type="search" data-wrapper-class="inputWrap" />
    </div>
</div>

.inputWrap {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 4px;
}
.btnclass {
    margin-top: 8px;
    height: 37px;
}
```

> **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/umkta1La/4/)**